# The type or namespace name 'MaxLengthAttributeAdapter' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

i created my custom data annotation attributes and tried to register 'em in global.asax
but faced with issue: The type or namespace name 'MaxLengthAttributeAdapter' could not be found
[image: MaxLengthAttributeAdapter]

does anybody know what's wrong ?
thanks in advance!

[UPD]
the namespace is added:

[image: namespace]

the references are added too:

[image: references]

Answer (score 0):

Registering it in Global.asax, does not negate the need to add references in other areas of your code that refer to it. Add the proper `using Namespace.To.MaxLengthAttributeAdapter;` line to the .cs file that's complaining.

Comment: the proper namespace and reference are added too (see images above), but it doesn't help. what is strange - the other attribute adapters which are in the same namespace\assembly were added with no probs